# cache the variable in constructor C#

Tags: c#

i have one class with constractor like this

```
public class product_new : NK.Objects._product_new
{
    private int Count_Per_Page;
    public product_new(int count_per_page)
    {
        this.Count_Per_Page = count_per_page;
    }
    public int CountOP///////count of pages
    {
        get
        {
            return number_of_pages(Count_Per_Page);
        }
    }
```

as you see the CountOP is return a int value and it is connect to sql database to return this value.

```
 private int number_of_pages(int tedad_per_pages)
 {
     return Q.Get_Back_Number_Of_Pages(
         tedad_per_pages, 
         tbl_name, 
         "", 
         new Queries.Cmd_Parameters());
 }
```

in several time if create object from this class the CountOP is not changed but the function number_of_pages is released and connect to the sql database.

how can i cache this variable?

Comment: Your question would be much easier to read if you'd follow regular .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Add following line to your code:  private static Dictionary<int,int> numberOfPages = new Dictionary<int,int>(); Then use numberOfPages in your methon "number_of_pages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `static Dictionary<int, int>` - *one* dictionary for *all* the instances:

```
  public class product_new : NK.Objects._product_new {
    // Simplest, but not thread safe; use ConcurrentDictionary for thread safe version
    private static Dictionary<int, int> s_KnownAnswers = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // Lazy: do not execute expensive operation eagerly: in the constructor;
    // but lazyly: in the property where we have to perform it
    public int CountOP {
      get {
        int result = 0;

        // do we know the answer? If yes, then just return it
        if (s_KnownAnswers.TryGetValue(Count_Per_Page, out result)) 
          return result;

        // if no, ask RDMBS
        result = number_of_pages(Count_Per_Page);

        // and store the result as known answer
        s_KnownAnswers.Add(Count_Per_Page, result); 

        return result;
      }
   }

    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a private backing-field that holds the value and initialize its value within your constructor. Now you can return the variables value within your getter instead of hitting the database every time you call the getter.

```
public class product_new : NK.Objects._product_new
{
    private int Count_Per_Page;
    private readonly int _CountOP;

    public product_new(int count_per_page)
    {
        this.Count_Per_Page = count_per_page;
        this._CountOP = number_of_pages(count_per_page);
    }
    public int CountOP///////count of pages
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CountOP;
        }
    }
```

Apart from this I strongly suggest to have a look at [Mircrsofts naming-conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Change to use a backed property:

```
private int _npages = -1;
public int CountOP///////count of pages
    {
        get
        {
            if(_npages == -1)
                _npages = number_of_pages(Count_Per_Page);
            return _npages;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Or use an `int?` and test for null. Nullables were added so that you didn't have to have "magic" values to indicate uninitialized values.

Comment: Well the problem with that is you then need to cast off, or propagate the nullable type everywhere, when it is clear the usage of the -1 as its located just above the property.

Comment: No you don't. `private int? _npages`, then `public int CountOP` tests `_npages == null` and ultimately returns `_npages.Value`. No code consuming `CountOP` needs to know or care that the backing field is `int?`. Whereas using `_npages = -1`, everybody has to know and care (including the database) that `-1` is special and can't be used anywhere else.

Comment: using value still casts it, its just does it for you

Comment: No it doesn't: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e

Comment: according to this it does: A nullable type can be cast to a regular type, either explicitly with a cast, or by using the Value property.  found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types

Comment: At any rate its still a valid answer, happy coding

Comment: The source code is pretty clear. Also, why would you actually care whether or not it casts? Versus making your code less readable and adding a secret hidden special value that a consumer (or the code responsible for producing the value) needs to know about.

Comment: NO one, and I mean NO ONE, would EVER see the -1, EVER. Also the -1 is the same as using a nullable type, only instead its using a -1. so really I dont see the point of your discussion, have a nice day.

Comment: If `Get_Back_Number_Of_Pages` should ever return -1 to indicate some special status, your code breaks. The maintainer of `Get_Back_Number_Of_Pages` _has to know_ that your code relies on -1 not being a valid value. That's the kind of time bomb you should avoid leaving in your code.